# Vimgrep: select different files in quickfix list without switching window?

Tags: quickfix, vimgrep

Let's say I have some file

```
a
asdf
b
asdf
c
```

and search `:vimgrep /asdf/g %`, and open the quickfix list `:copen`. Now I can navigate between the two results using `j/k` and jump to said result using `Enter`.
I find it inconvenient that we directly switch from the quickfix window to the window with the result.
So far I just mapped `:cprev` and `:cnext` to some keys, but I'm wondering:

Is there some other short cut that acts like hitting `Enter`, but without switching to the result (i.e. staying in the quickfix list)?

Comment: You can easily map <CR> to behave differently in qflist (e.g., if in qflist, map to `<CR>:cw<CR>`). But I think your mapping of `:cprev` and `:cnext` is much more useful and hasslefree. Normally, specially in `:grep` as opposed to `:make`, user should not even care about the qflist. Just cycle through the results _with_ proper and ample context. (In `:make`, one needs to read the error message, so that's a different matter.)

Comment: @kadekai Thank you for the advice, that is a very good point! I think I'll stick with that then!

Comment: @kadekai unless one wants to inspect the results/filter further/etc., in which case viewing the list is very handy.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own mapping that opens the quickfix entry and comes back. Taken from [vim-qf](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf/blob/master/after/ftplugin/qf.vim#L79):

```
" in after/ftplugin/qf.vim
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> o <CR><C-w>p
```

See `:help CTRL-W_p`.